# JDBC runs in pure Java, but not in Android

Tags: java, android

This code **runs OK** in a pure Java application:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement inst;

    try {

        Class.forName ("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance ();

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;DatabaseName=Prueba", "sa", "sa1234");
        inst = conn.createStatement();

        inst.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TIENDAS(NOMBRE) VALUES ('ZZZZZZZ') ");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in Android project I get the error **'Socket closed'**.

I'm using Eclipse Helios.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you doing that in the emulator? Can you display e.g. a web page on 192.168.1.100 from the device/emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android isn't a full implementation of Java so this driver, if it is a type 4 driver, could be using some features in Java that haven't been ported to Android.  That's first and foremost the concern about using code in Android without knowing if it will actually run on Android.

Now a more general concern about what you're doing.  Unless you are developing an SQL browser for android I'd be very concerned about what you are doing.  In order for your Android client to see the DB means it has to be exposed over the internet.  That's a seriously bad idea.  Exposing your DB to the rest of the world means they don't have to use your app to connect to it.  I can fire up any old SQL browser and start guessing passwords, hacking around, trying default accounts.  So if you haven't locked down your DB it's not a question of if someone will hack it, but when.

You shouldn't be directly accessing a remotely accessible DB from Android without going through an APP server like Tomcat, Jetty, etc.  Rule of thumb:  If you find yourself opening up your DB ports on the firewall to everyone to get your solution to work.  You are definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: +1. You should really be accessing a DB through an API of sorts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're absolutely right, but you do not answer me.

Comment: I think you should keep your database behind firewall. So the user first needs to connect to your network via VPN and then the rest is up to how you offer  :)

Comment: @TheVanix what I'm saying is that you shouldn't waste your time trying to get that driver working on Android in the first place because you should be going through an app server using an API you design around your data.  That JDBC driver should be loaded by the app server, which would be a pure java program, and your application will expose access to it through JSON or some other higher level object model.  Therefore, the fact that it doesn't' work on Android is irrelevant.  So yes I didn't answer your question, but you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the internet permission defined in the Android Manifest?